# iOS Google maps sdk cannot connect

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

**I am a complete newbie to iOS development.**

I am trying to use a google maps view (using storyboards as [Google ios sdk mapview with storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025864/google-ios-sdk-mapview-with-storyboards)). I have setup the project as required by the SDK, included the required libraries, copied the bundle into the framework folder... but i am getting this error NSLog'd to the output window

```
2013-03-25 19:52:25.315 TaxiQ[688:7203] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.1.1.2311
2013-03-25 19:52:25.354 TaxiQ[688:c07] Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6
2013-03-25 19:52:25.365 TaxiQ[688:c07] GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 10)
2013-03-25 19:52:25.366 TaxiQ[688:c07] GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 15)
2013-03-25 19:52:26.783 TaxiQ[688:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 100.)"
2013-03-25 19:52:26.933 TaxiQ[688:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 100.)"
2013-03-25 19:52:31.068 TaxiQ[688:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 100.)"
2013-03-25 19:52:39.209 TaxiQ[688:c07] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 100.)"
2013-03-25 19:52:39.209 TaxiQ[688:c07] Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.Maps.GMSDASHConnection error 100.)
```

Do i have to declare i have to access the internet in any way? I come from an android background where you do have to declare so.

Comment: Did you set the api key with `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:API_KEY]`? Also first read the *getting started guide*: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: I did provide the key, the method is returning YES. As for reading the getting started guide: i did, but i mentioned that link so to make the way i am instantiating the map explicit

Comment: *Your PI key may be invalid for your bundle ID*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, forgot the bundle identifier is Case Sensitive.

The map is now working as i fixed the identifier in the apis console

Answer (score 17):

When trying to add Google Maps I was receiving error due to the fact that I did not select both the "Google Maps API V3" and "Google Maps SDK for IOS" when authorizing my AIP access in the [google console](https://code.google.com/). Seems like a simple mistake, but if you do not have both of these services selected it's possible to get this "cannot connect or validate APIKey" error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please check your bundle identifier in project - it should match from the bundle identifier entered in google's app created by you.

Answer (score 0):

i put it in the url identifier and it didnt work until i realised its supposed to be in the IOS Applicatiion target identifier (using Xamarin studio).

Answer (score 0):

If u want to add framework to project then download sdk 1.9 from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases#version_1130_-_march_29_2016 and follow same procedure as https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/ios-get-started

Answer (score 0):

A good way to debug this issue is to test your API Key in Google's demo app.

[Here are the instructions in the documentation to install the demo app using cocoapods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/code-samples#try-the-sdk-demos-using-cocoapods).

*Make sure to add the bundle id from the demo app to your API Key in the Credentials section of Google's API Manager web interface.*

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I need to test my app with dates if the future and in the past. It can make the APIKey check fail because of backdated certificates.

Be sure to set your device with the actual date.